# Jenkins pipeline build stuck forever if node doesn't exist

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, agent

I have a Jenkins pipeline like:

```
node("slave1"){
  echo "Building very very complicated things"
}
```

If the node "slave1" does not exist in my Jenkins setup, the build is stuck forever.

I know I could use `timeout` keyword and wrap the `node` command. However, this is not good since timeout can happen because of inexistent node or long-taking build. That's not really a solution.

Any calls that I can do to check if a node exists or not?

I use Jenkins 2.32.2 and pipeline plugin version 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `timeout` like you say, only having the `node` do something trivial to test the water. If that succeeds you'll know "slave1" exists and can call `node` again to do the actual build.

Comment: That's a very good  approach, thanks. However, I am actually spawning containers on a Kubernetes cluster. So, that means I spawn an extra container for just testing the water.

If there is a way to check if a node exists, or if a handler exists for node name programmatically?

Comment: There must be a better solution to this problem IMO.